# Integral test for convergence of $\frac{1}{\ln x}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I want to know if

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln x}\, dx$$

converges or not.

Comment: You may find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Comment: See how it behaves near $1$. $\log (1-\varepsilon) = - \varepsilon - \frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^2 - \dotsc$.

Answer (score 2):

A series expansions shows that
$$
\frac1{\ln(x)}=\frac1{x-1}+\frac12+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{b_n}(x-1)^n+\cdots
$$
and the integral of $\frac1{x-1}$ diverges at $1$. It is sufficient to show that 
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac1{x-1}\, dx
$$
converges. Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x}-\frac1{x-1}$, then $f(0)=1$ , according to the above expansion $f(1)=\frac12$ and continous in between, therefore the integral is finite. According to [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e2gg4h5kj51) this is $\gamma=0.577...$

Answer (score 2):

$x=1$ is a simple zero for $\log(x)$, hence $f(x)=\frac{1}{\log x}$ has a simple pole in $x=1$ and a simple pole is a non-integrable singularity. For instance:

$$ \int_{0}^{e^{-\varepsilon}}\frac{dx}{\left|\log x\right|}=\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t\,e^t}\geq\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{e^{2t}-e^t}\geq -1+\log\frac{1}{1-e^{-\varepsilon}}\geq -1-\log\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1/n}^{1-1/n} \dfrac{1}{\ln x}\, dx\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\ln x\right)\Big|_{1/n}^{1-1/n}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\dfrac{\ln n-\ln(n-1)}{\ln n}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(1-\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln (n-1)}{\ln n}\right)\\
&\to \color{Purple}{-\infty}\end{align}
$$